# Codenameone1 Cloudinary breaks on an IOS device

Tags: ios, codenameone

When running on an IOS device Cloudinary constructor throws the following exception:

> com.codename1.util.regex.RESYntaxException.Syntaxerror: Unmatched
>   Close paren...

```
new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
                  "cloud_name", my_cloud_name,
                  "api_key", my_api_key,
                  "api_secret", my_api_secret));
```

Are there any HTTP calls in the Cloudinary port?

It works just fine in the simulator. I didn't check on Android.

The image is fetched through this URL:

https://res.cloudinary.com/...

Thanks

Comment: Constructor does not fail - image fetch fails. First it throws the above exception - then returns blank images - with correct size though.

Comment: cloudinary.config.secure = true; and the request goes through https

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the exception? It looks like a regular expression failed somewhere but it's hard to see where.

Comment: Have on device only :com.codename1.util.regex.RESYntaxException.Syntaxerror: Unmatched Close paren...

Comment: You can use DDMS or logcat to see the output of an Android device and see the full stack trace.

Comment: Have a similar (the same?) problem:
(Works fine in simulator and on Android)

`
com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException
at com_codename1_util_regex_RECompiler.syntaxError:231
at com_codename1_util_regex_RECompiler.compile:1283
at com_codename1_util_regex_RE.__INIT__:407
at com_codename1_util_regex_RE.__INIT__:393
at com_cloudinary_Pattern.compile:22
at com_cloudinary_Url.__CLINIT__:78
at com_cloudinary_Cloudinary.url:100
`